# How to count occurrence of unknown strings in column?

Tags: string, r, count

I have another question.  Thanks for everyone's help and patience with an R newbie!

How can I count how many times a string occurs in a column? Example:

```
MYdata <- data.frame(fruits = c("apples", "pears", "unknown_f", "unknown_f", "unknown_f"), 
                     veggies = c("beans", "carrots", "carrots", "unknown_v", "unknown_v"), 
                     sales = rnorm(5, 10000, 2500))
```

The problem is that my real data set contains several thousand rows and several hundred of the unknown fruits and unknown veggies. I played around with "table()" and "levels" but without much success.  I guess it's more complicated than that.  Great would be to have an output table listing the name of each unique fruit/veggie and how many times it occurs in its column. Any hint in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Marcus

Comment: In what way was `table(MYdata$fruits)` unsatisfactory?

Comment: Wow! I really have to apologize for this!! I spent half a day on this ... tried varies iterations of table() ... but - I promise - never got anything useful. I guess I missed the forest for the trees. Thanks everyone for your helpful answers and comments! Marcus

Answer (score 10):

If I understand your question, the function `table()` should work just fine.  Here is how:

```
table(MYdata$fruits)

   apples     pears unknown_f 
        1         1         3 
table(MYdata$veggies)

    beans   carrots unknown_v 
        1         2         2
```

---

Or use `table` inside `lapply`:

```
lapply(MYdata[1:2], table)
$fruits

   apples     pears unknown_f 
        1         1         3 

$veggies

    beans   carrots unknown_v 
        1         2         2
```

Comment: Thank you! I am sorry it was so easy.  See my comment above.

Answer (score 3):

The following gives you a data frame of counts which you might find easier to use or may suit your purposes better:

```
tabs=lapply(MYdata[-3], table)
out=data.frame(item=names(unlist(tabs)),count=unlist(tabs)[],
               stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
rownames(out)=c()

print(out)

               item count
1     fruits.apples     1
2      fruits.pears     1
3  fruits.unknown_f     3
4     veggies.beans     1
5   veggies.carrots     2
6 veggies.unknown_v     2
```

Comment: This solution is especially nice since the output is a data frame and not a table, which may be a pain to manipulate later.

Comment: I have been looking for code that does just this for a long time!!  Thank you, thank you!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like

```
summary(MYdata$fruits)
```

Comment: thank you! As a newbie I was not really aware of the summary() command.